# How to add custom fields in google contacts API V3 with json

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-api-client, google-contacts-api

API Request

```
POST https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?alt=json
```

Body

```
{
    "entry": {
        "gd$name": {
            "gd$fullName": {
                "$t": "Rohit Roy"
            },
            "gd$givenName": {
                "$t": "Rohit"
            },
            "gd$familyName": {
                "$t": "Roy"
            }
        },
        "gd$email": [
            {
                "address": "royrohit1234@exampledomain.com",
                "primary": "true",
                "rel": "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#home"
            }
        ],
        "gd$phoneNumber": {
            "$t": "+919999888877",
            "primary": "true",
            "rel": "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#home"
        },
        "gd$organization": {
            "gd$orgName": {
                "$t": "XYZ Pvt. ltd."
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code is working properly i want to add custom fields to google contacts.

For that i tried convert below XML into JSON.

```
<gContact:userDefinedField key="chess" value="likes playing black"/>
```

Like This

```
"gContact$userDefinedField":{
        "key":"food",
        "value":"Chinese"
        }
```

But this code is not working with above code so i need help to add custom field with my working code above.

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately i got solution of custom fields, birthday and all other google contact fields with JSON API.

Google Contact API Docs updated and mentioned about [Peoples API](https://developers.google.com/people/v1/contacts#create-a-new-contact) which is replacement of old google contact API.

So now i am using Peoples API instead of Contacts API V3 which already deprecated.

[Click This Link For Peoples API Create Contact API Docs](https://developers.google.com/people/v1/contacts#create-a-new-contact)

HTTP Request

```
POST https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people:createContact
```

Body

```
{
  "emailAddresses": [
        {
            "value": "rohitroy@exampledomain.com",
            "type": "work"
        }
    ],
  "names": [{
        "givenName": "John",
        "familyName": "Doe"
    }],
        "birthdays": [
        {
            "date": {
                "year": 1996,
                "month": 5,
                "day": 2
            }
        }
    ],
    "userDefined": [
        {
            "key": "customfield",
            "value": "anyvalue-123456"
        }
    ]
}
```

In the Body userDefined is for custom fields.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Did you manage to make it work with the Contacts API outside of Apps Script with an XML?

Comment: Yes @ziganotschka this is working without Apps Script and i am using Peoples API instead of Contact API V3 which is deprecated by google contact new recommended API for Google contacts is Peoples API which is based on JSON so XML not required.

Comment: @ziganotschka Also added a example for adding birthday and custom-fields by Peoples API.